# macOS にて Homebrew がインストールできません

Tags: homebrew

公式ホームページにて以下のコマンドをターミナル でするように指示があるのですが

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

色々調べるとXcodeとコマンドラインツールが必要とのことでインストールしたのですが、それでも変わらずの反応です。

なにか別途インストールする必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 参考になるかわかりませんが macOS Mojave では Xcode を App Store からダウンロードしてインストールし Command Line Tools for Xcode は xcode-select --install でインストールした後に Homebrew をインストールできました。 少なくとも Mojave では別途必要なインストールはありませんでした。

Comment: コマンドライン内に埋め込まれている`curl`コマンドが「SSL証明書の問題」を示しているので「コマンドラインツールが必要」になるようなところまでたどり着けていないようです。HomeBrewの公式コミュニティーに[同様のエラーが質問されていました](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/cant-install-homebrew-on-macos-mojave-ssl-error/4982)。最終的な解決策は示されていませんでしたが、ネットワーク環境の問題で証明書が書き換えられているのが原因ではないかと書かれています。[メッセージ中のリンク先](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html)を参照して、`curl`コマンドの証明書検証の部分を突破する必要があるだろうと思います。(一番簡単なのは証明書検証を無効化するってやつですが、リスクが高まります。)

Comment: mac にセキュリティソフトをインストールがされている、または会社や学校で外部との接続にファイアウォールを通す環境だったりしませんか？ / 別の回避策としては、対象の URL をブラウザで開いて保存し、保存したファイルを実行すれば良さそうな気もします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。セキュリティソフトを無効化したら無事にできました！

Comment: 解決したようで何よりです。もし良ければ解決に至った手順 (セキュリティソフトは何を使っていた、どんなふうに無効化したか…etc) を [自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) の形で投稿してもらうと、同じような問題で困ったユーザーの助けになると思います。

Comment: お返事遅れてしまい、申し訳ありません。セキュリティソフトのカスペルスキーを無効化したらうまく行きました。無効化は以下のような方法でしました。
https://support.kaspersky.com/KIS4Mac/16.0/ja.lproj/pgs/58285.htm