# homebrewをインストールしてmysqlをインストールしたいです。

Tags: mysql, homebrew

homebrewのインストールurlをターミナルに打ち込むと次の様な表示が出てきます。

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
(base) macuser@Mac-no-MacBook-Air-4 ~ %
```

上記urlに接続しても何も分かりません。
アップルストア、pcデポの遠隔サポートでも分からなかったのですが、どなたか対処法をご存知ないでしょうか。

Comment: エラーメッセージだけでなく、実行したコマンドも質問中に追記してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

[過去にも類似の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70548) がありますが、mac 上でウィルス対策ソフトを利用している場合には (一時的に) 無効にすることで問題が解決するかもしれません。

もしくは会社や学校などの LAN 環境からファイアウォール越しにネットワーク接続をしている場合に問題が出ている可能性もあります。こちらの場合はネットワーク管理者に問い合わせてみてください。